# AnyLogic: Pick products from a specific cell in storage rack

Tags: storage, cell, rack, anylogic, picking

I am trying to pick products from a specific cell from a storage rack/storage system. In the RackStore block, it is possible to store products in a specific cell by providing the row, position and level.

When the product is stored in this specific cell, I want to retrieve it later on from this specific cell. So, I want to pick a product using rackPick block (or any other block) by giving the inputs row, position and level.

So for example, I have product A stored in row 1, position 20 and level 2. I want to pick the product from this specific cell. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how RackStore and RackPick work. There are product-centric so essentially, it is your product "picking itself" when it starts to enter the RackPick element.

Because the product was stored into cell 1/20/2 when it left its RackStore element, it remembers that and is picked from that location.

So you do not need to worry where to pick your product from, it knows where it lives.

Instead, your problem is likely where to store products, which you can define in RackStore explicitly.

Or your actual problem is *when* to release stored products into RackPick so they are picked up again, but that would be done in a delay/hold block upstream of RackPick.

cheers

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thank you for your fast response. I was indeed looking at this wrongly and your answer helped me a lot. However, I have one additional question; I store Handling Units in the storage rack. A Handling Unit consists of multiple items and I want to retrieve these items one-by-one until the number of items in the Handling Unit is reached. I am now able to retrieve the entire Handling Unit from the storage rack, but is it also possible to retrieve items from this Handling Unit without retrieving the actual Handling Unit from the storage rack? Thanks a lot in advance. Kind regards Kevin

Comment: sure, but please put this into a new, separate question (helps others in the future). Also, if this answer was helpful, please mark it as "useful" (up-arrow on the left of my reply). Again this helps future folks finding answers faster. Welcome to SOF. Do check how this site works and this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask